# Dynamic VLOOKUP in VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I want a formula in a cell like below

```
=VLOOKUP(B3,Release!A:B,2,FALSE) </i>
```

for that I am using the below VBA code.

```
    lookup_cell = "B" & I
Formula_cell = "=VLOOKUP(" & lookup_cell & ",Release!A:B" & ",2,FALSE)"
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = Formula_cell
```

But I am getting the formula like below

`=VLOOKUP('B3',Release!A:(B),2,FALSE)`

Kindly help me to understand why i am getting the single quotes around B3 and why i am getting brakes around B.?

Answer (score 1):

Your formula is not in R1C1 format, so you shouldn't use the `FormulaR1C1` property but rather use `Formula` instead:

```
ActiveCell.Formula = Formula_cell
```

Comment: Thank you so much. It is working now. but why i am getting '' and () in my previous formula

Comment: Because your references are A1 style and Excel can't parse them into R1C1 properly.